# Responsive design for mobile websites

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm going to adapt my website for mobile devices. Should I create a sub domain for the mobile version (m.mysite.com) or should I use media queries in CSS? My first choice was media queries, but today's phones carries screens with the same resolution as on PC monitors - which makes media queries ineffective. Or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer a responsive design.

I only choose a sub-domain as solution when i'm building a big website.

If you take a responsive design, take a look to bootstrap and foundation.

- http://getbootstrap.com/
- http://foundation.zurb.com/

My advice:

Are you building a big website with a lot of content/data. Use a sub-domain for the mobile website.

If it's just a small website for a small business. Make the website responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries. Although the amount of pixels are the same, these phones use double pixel ratio, so the intended design can be used but with crisper graphics and text. For example, an iPhone 5 has `device-pixel-ratio=2`, which means that your element with 200px width will take up 400px on the iPhone's screen.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, for SEO reasons, I thing it would be better for you to use a directory and not a sub-domain. 
In general, search engines prefer mobile responsive websites and 'rank' it higher.

In my opinion, make it mobile responsive either way.